# How to create a Raycast that will allow a turret to see if a player is behind a wall?

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

so, basically, I have created a pretty simple turret script that basically just smoothly aims at the player, so long as the player is within a certain amount of range. The problem I am having, is that the Raycast I wrote that actually checks if the 'bullet' (which is nothing  - it's just a raycast), would hit the target. This means that even if the player hides behind a wall, the turret can still shoot him.
My current raycast script allows the raycast to go straight through the wall, and since I am new to Unity, I have no idea how to make it check if the first object it hits is the player, so that it cannot go through walls.
Here is my current raycast script:

```
void Shoot()
{

    //I think the problem is here - I want the raycast to return false if it hits a wall - which has the layer "ground", and true if it hits the player. Problem is, I need to make the turret return to resting position when the player is behind a wall.
    //To do this, I can just set inRange = true; But I need to be able to determine when the player is behind a wall.

    LayerMask layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Player");

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))

    {
        //This determines how much damage will the player take.
        int damage = Random.Range(1, 5);

        hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<playerMovement>().Shot(damage);

        //I personally THINK this means that it only triggers collisions with the player, which is why it is not working. 
        // The player has layer "Player", and tag "Player", so if anyone who wants to help can figure out how to make it stop when it hits anything - and then only return true if it hit the player (meaning the player is not behind walls).
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you'd need to do is cast from the turret to the player and detect what the raycast has hit. Your current code is setting a mask to only be on the player, so it will never hit a wall. You can change your code to something like this:

```
private LayerMask layerMask = (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player") | (1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("ground")));

void Update () {
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
    {
        if(hit.collider.gameObject.layer == LayerMask.NameToLayer("Player"))
        {
            // you can shoot as you see the player   
        }
        else
        {
            // you hit the ground - player is behind a wall   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that's very helpful. I had an idea of what was wrong, but no idea to solve it until now. I should have known to use a layer mask with both layers. Oh well, hopefully I won't make the same mistake in the future.

Comment: @Hchap No worries! It happens to everyone, all part of programming. If this post answered your question, you can close the question by clicking the arrow to the left of the post. By doing so, it will let anyone else who finds your question know it has an answer.

Comment: Note that [`GameObject.layer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-layer.html) is an `int` ;)

Comment: @derHugo Right would need to convert it to an int using `NameToLayer`. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if there is anything between the player and the Raycast, then simply remove the Layermask

Change this:

```
 LayerMask layerMask = LayerMask.GetMask("Player");

if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward), out RaycastHit hit, Mathf.Infinity, layerMask))
```

To this:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward));

if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit hit) {..}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to

- remove the check for the layer in order to hit everything with the raycast
- then you can use [`TryGetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.TryGetComponent.html) to check whether the hit object has such component attached or not
- and in general instead of

  ```c#
  transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward)
  ```

  simply use [`transform.forward`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) ;)

So something like

```c#
void Shoot()
{
    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transform.forward, out var hit))
    {
        // Without the need for any tag or layer check
        // Simply check if the object you hit has a playerMovement component
        // GetComponent was improved a lot lately and now uses hashes
        // it's not that performance intense anymore and almost as fast as CompareTag
        if(hit.gameObject.TryGetComponent<playerMovement>(out var movement)
        {
            int damage = Random.Range(1, 5);

            movement.Shot(damage);
        }
    }
}
```